# Create sleep(); call Using llvm IRbuilder

Tags: c++, llvm-ir

What is the LLVM-IR builder instruction to create an instruction similar to this:

```
%call4 = call i32 (i32, ...)* bitcast (i32 (...)* @sleep to i32 (i32, ...)*)(i32 3)
```

Is there a way to call directly the @sleep or do I need to create a new function for it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ConstantInt *sleepArg = ConstantInt::get(IntegerType::get(getGlobalContext(), sizeof(unsigned) * 8), 2 ,true);

```
    std::vector<Value*> args2;
    args2.push_back(sleepArg);      

    Constant *D = M.getOrInsertFunction("sleep", 
    IntegerType::get(getGlobalContext(), sizeof(unsigned) * 8),
    IntegerType::get(getGlobalContext(), sizeof(unsigned) * 8), NULL);
```